# Nginx blocks data from HTML Form

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have Flask app which is using HTML form to get the data from user, run it through bash script and return it to the user via another HTML. Everything works fine if I run it through command line `python3 app.py`, but when it's handled by NGINX no data is in `request.form.get('email')`.

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess
app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = "/home/my_site/templates/static"

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def show_index_html():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/send_data', methods = ['POST'])
def get_email_from_html():
    email = request.form.get('email') ###No data here
    output = subprocess.run(['/home/path_to_script/query.sh', email], capture_output=True)
    score = output.stdout
    return render_template('output.html', output=score)


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    app.run(ssl_context=('mailcheck.crt','mailcheck.key'),host="0.0.0.0", port=8888,debug=True)
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8>
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"> 
    <form method="POST" action="/send_data">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <span>E-mail :</span>
            <input type="email" class="email_form" name="email" maxlength="30">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send">
    </form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

site.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master=true
processes = 5

socket = site.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Nginx Server Block

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name mailcheck.mysite.com www.mailcheck.mysite.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/soc/site/site.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mailcheck.mysite.com www.mailcheck.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get data from your form you can use either this:

```
request.form['input_name']
```

or

```
request.form.get('input_name', 0)
```

Comment: Originally I was using `request.form['input_name']`, then I changed it to `request.form.get('input_name', 0)` to see if that makes a difference, but unfortunately, it's still the same

Comment: Try to set the ssl certificate through nginx app and not through Flask app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately the only thing that has changed is that when I run the app through python it is HTTP instead of HTTPS

Comment: it could be the port that flask runs on by default, I haven't used ngnx to run a flask app though cos it comes with its own web library. How about your debug it and see if your can hit an empty endpoint that return something like hello?